# Se cambia solo el Idioma predeterminado MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Tengo una base de datos en un servidor pero por más veces que le ponga el idioma predeterminado en inglés de la nada se cambia a arabic. Alguien que sepa el porque y como solucionarlo? Me genera inconvenientes con el sistema de las otras computadoras conectadas a esa base de datos.

Comment: Cuándo dices "por mas veces que _ponga_ el idioma...", ¿en dónde _pones_ el idioma predeterminado?